# Software Design: Model method which model should belong

Tags: design-patterns

I am pretty sure this has been asked many times but I cannot think of a good search phrase to get some useful results, so I am going to ask again:

Lets say I have 3 model domains (apps), if expressed in django framework:

```
class User(Model):
    pass

class Content(Model):
    pass

class Comment(Model):
    created_by = ForeignKey(User)
    content = ForeignKey(Content)
```

If I want add a method to create a comment object, which Model should I implement the method in? I am in the dilemma between Content and User.

If it's user centric:

```
Class User(Model):
    def add_comment(content, message):
        ....
```

If it's content centric:

```
Class Comment(Model):
    def add_comment(user, message):
        ....
```

Is there a golden rule to decide? Or does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should follow [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Comments are handled by Comments model. They are separated from the user. So, you should create comments from Comments model.

Also by passing information about one model to another, use [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Do not pass the whole object. Only fields, that are absolutely required to perform request. In your case user_id is sufficient to create a comment. No need to pass along user model.

It would probably better to implement some methods to link related models if you are reinventing your own ORM now ;)

Comment: Thanks, while I agree on the first paragraph, also understands what law of demeter means, I am a little bit reluctant to agree on second paragraph, yes, I wouldn't pass the whole request object to a method which only interested in a query param, but in this case (especially in django's ORM) I think it's appropriate to pass in the user object.

Comment: @JamesLin I never tried to use Django, so you may be correct ;) In Laravel (PHP ORM) you should also pass a model into some ORM method like save(): http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent So, you are probably right here.